# Upload image to SQL server using view, view model, and controller

Tags: c#, sql-server, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, image-uploading

I'm in VS 2013 and am completely new to ASP.NET MVC in general. I have been attempting to do this for sometime with no luck. Have a user complete a form with an image upload, and have that form with the image written to the DB. I know its best to write the path to the DB and store the image in the content folder of the application but I have no idea how to do any of this. Can someone give me a starting point?

I also have a `ClientUtility.cs` that is used to populate drop-downs but I don't see this being needed right now.

Currently the data type for the image ref in the db is `VARCHAR(255)`.

`Controller`:

```
    private TpsEntities db = new TpsEntities();
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveStaffDetails(RegisterStaffViewModel model)
    {

        var staff = new staffTable()
        {
            staffFirstName = model.FirstName,
            staffLastName = model.LastName,
            staffTitle = model.SelectedTitle,
            staffAddress = model.Address,
            staffCity = model.City,
            staffState = model.SelectedState,
            staffZip = model.ZipCode,
            staffExperience = model.SelectedExperience,
            staffEducation = model.SelectedEducation,
            desiredSalary = model.SelectedSalary,
            staffProfession = model.SelectedProfession,
            staffAvailibity = model.SelectedAvailability,
            staffEmail = model.EmailAddress,
            staffPhoneNum = model.PhoneNumber,
            staffPhoto = null,
            userID = model.UserId
        };

        using (var db = new TpsEntities())
        {
            db.staffTables.Add(staff);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        var userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var user = userManager.FindById(model.UserId);

        userManager.AddToRole(model.UserId, "Staff");

        ClaimsIdentity identity = userManager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Staff"));


        var AuthenticationManager = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;

        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() {IsPersistent = false}, identity);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

`ViewModel`:

```
public class RegisterStaffViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public string SelectedTitle { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "City")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    public System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection States { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "State")]
    public string SelectedState { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Zip Code")]
    public double? ZipCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Phone]
    [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection Experience { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Experience")]
    public string SelectedExperience { get; set; }

    public System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection Education { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Education")]
    public string SelectedEducation { get; set; }

    public System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection Salary { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Salary")]
    public string SelectedSalary { get; set; }

    public System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection Profession { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Profession")]
    public string SelectedProfession { get; set; }

    public System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection Availability { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Availability")]
    public string SelectedAvailability { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

`View`:

```
@*Start of Registration Form for Staff*@

@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveStaffDetails", "Staff", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserId)
            <fieldset>

                <!-- Form Name -->
                <legend>Register New Staff</legend>

                @*First Name*@
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control input-md", @placeholder = "First Name" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                @*Last Name*@
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "form-control input-md", @placeholder = "Last Name" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                @*Person Title*@
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-6 control-label" for="title">Title</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedTitle, new SelectList(Model.Title, "Text", "Value"))
                    </div>
                </div>


                @*Address Line*@
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address, new { @class = "form-control input-md", @placeholder = "Address" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                @*City*@
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.City, new { @class = "form-control input-md", @placeholder = "City" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                @*State*@
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-6 control-label" for="state">State</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedState, new SelectList(Model.States, "Text", "Value"))
                    </div>
                </div>

                @*Zip Code*@
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ZipCode, new { @class = "form-control input-md", @placeholder = "Zip Code" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                @*Phone Number*@
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNumber, new { @class = "form-control input-md", @placeholder = "Phone Number" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                @*Email Address*@
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress, new { @class = "form-control input-md", @placeholder = "Email Address" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                @*Experience*@
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-6 control-label" for="experience">Experience</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedExperience, new SelectList(Model.Experience, "Text", "Value"))
                    </div>
                </div>

                @*Education*@
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-6 control-label" for="education">Education</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedEducation, new SelectList(Model.Education, "Text", "Value"))
                    </div>
                </div>

                @*Desired Salary*@
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-6 control-label" for="salary">Desired Salary</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSalary, new SelectList(Model.Salary, "Text", "Value"))
                    </div>
                </div>

                @*Profession*@
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-6 control-label" for="profession">Profession</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedProfession, new SelectList(Model.Profession, "Text", "Value"))
                    </div>
                </div>

                @*Availability*@
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-6 control-label" for="availability">Availability</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedAvailability, new SelectList(Model.Availability, "Text", "Value"))
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- INSERT IMAGE UPLOAD HERE -->
            </fieldset>

            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your controller as the following code.I assumed that staffPhoto is taking picturepath.

```
public ActionResult SaveStaffDetails(RegisterStaffViewModel model,HttpPostedFileBase image)
{
    if (Request.Files.Count > 0) {
        string FileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "");
        string Path = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Request.Files[0].FileName);
        string FullPath = "~/Images/StaffPhotos/" + FileName + Path;
        Request.Files[0].SaveAs(Server.MapPath(FullPath));
        staffPhoto = FileName + Path;
    }
}
```

In your view you need a file post input

```
<input type="file" class="filestyle" name="image" data-classbutton="btn btn-primary" data-input="false">
```

Comment: I added what you indicated to the controller above var staff = new staffTable().  It doesn't take. staffPhoto does not exist in the current context.

Comment: It doesn't save because you don't have any variable in your model which will contain photopath.Include public string somethingPath{get; set;}In your db there must be a column which belongs to photopaths.